# can't detec case sensitive & show all data in a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

hello guys i'm trying to run my code but i have a problem
can't validate data with case sensitive and show all data in a spreadsheet

```html
 case "/material" :
      if (subPerintah == 'id admin') {
        sendText(updates.message.chat.id, searchAllData(subPerintah));
      } else {
      if (isUserAllow(updates.message.from.id) == 1){
        sendText(updates.message.chat.id, searchByTanggal(subPerintah)); 
      } else {
        let show =
            'User anda tidak diijinkan menggunakan bot ini \n\n' +
            
            'Untuk mendaftar silahkan kirim dengan cara: \n\n' +
            '/registrasi\n' +
            '____________________________________';
         sendText(updates.message.chat.id, cabutan);
      }
      }
    break;
```

the code above is useful for validating users who have registered or not

and this code to show all data and search data by material

```html
function AmbilMaterial() {
  var rangeName = 'Name Sheet!A2:F';
  var rows = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(SheetID, rangeName).values;
  return rows;
function searchAllData(id) {
  var dataMaterial = AmbilMaterial();
  var no = 1;
  var num = 1;
  const data = [];
  var header = '<b>Data Material</b>\n\n' +
    'Awal Tanggal :' + '<b>' + id + '</b>\n\n';
     var th = 
     '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  \n' +
     '<b>No. |Nama Lengkap|NIK|Material|Satuan|Tanggal</b> \n' +
     '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  \n';
  for (var row = 0; row < dataMaterial.length; row++) {
    if (dataMaterial[row][0] == id) { 
      var resi = num++ + '.' + dataMaterial[row][1] + ' | ' + dataMaterial[row][2] + ' | ' + dataMaterial[row][3] + ' | ' + dataMaterial[row][4] + ' | <b>' + dataMaterial[row][0] +'</b>\n\n';
      data.push(resi);             
    }
  }    
  var gabung1 = header + th + data;    
  var clearKoma1 = gabung1.toString();     
  var dataBaru1 = clearKoma1.replaceAll(',', '');        
  return dataBaru1;
}
```

[image]

thank you

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `but i have a problem can't validate data with case sensitive and show all data in a spreadsheet` and your provided scripts and your image, I cannot understand your current issue and your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Make it all lowercase: [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

Comment: Have you tried converting to lower case as mentioned on the last comment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73486037/18044060 my ask a new question sir  @TheMaster

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/73486037/18044060 this is my ask a new question  @Kessy

Comment: Your code is sort of fragmented so it is hard to tell what is the question and what is the problem.  It seems the question is about `id` in `searchAllData(id)`.  In your switch block in the first case `subPerintah == 'id admin'`, subPerintah is obviously defined but in the second case `if (isUserAllow(updates.message.from.id) == 1)` it may not be.  Check the value of subPerintah before in that block.  Also you seem to be missing a `}` before `function searchAllData(id) {`.

Comment: @Newbie That question is closed. You can [edit] the data here. Please don't include links or pictures. Use **plain text** to show 1. Script, 2. Expected results and 3. Actual results.